# Honeypot sample test Odd Numbers question

Tags: java

So there is a Sample Test publicly available on the Honeypot site, and I'm confused about one of the tests.

> 1 <= l <= r <= 10^5

l is starting number

r is ending number

Test is to return all the odd numbers between l and r including l and r if they happen to be odd.

This was my code in the function that runs and expects an arraylist of integers as a return value:

```
    List<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < r - l + 2; i++) {
        if ((l + i % 2) == 1)
            arraylist.add(l + i);
    }

    return arraylist;
```

This code passed 8 out of 12 test cases, it failed test cases 7 - 10, but it doesn't show the test cases that it failed.

I'm just curious about the test cases that this fails, cause I can't seem to figure it out.

In what circuimstances would this code fail to do what it set out to do?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know those testcases but your loop seems odd. Why not just `for( int i=l; i<=r; i++) { /*test here*/ }`?

Comment: Consider what the expression `l+i%2` really means (taking operator precedence into account)

Comment: consider l = r = 2 - it will fail...

Comment: Don't you have any validation for `1 <= l <= r <= 10^5` constraint? Maybe they have tests for that as well?

Comment: @Amongalen In those challenges (like [hackerhank](https://www.hackerrank.com/), for instance), the constraints doesn't need to be tested. These are assumptions on the problem's inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

1. `(l + i % 2)` : this will first compute `i % 2` then add it to `l` which is wrong
2. `r - l + 2` : this should changes to `r - l + 1`

This will helps you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < r - l + 1; i++) {
    if (((l + i) % 2) == 1) arraylist.add(l + i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not realise that (l + i % 2) would first compute the i % 2 and only add l AFTER. I've only been coding for roughly 2 months, and I had 10 minutes to solve this problem. This is the best I could come up with in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to apply `%2` on every number. Try below:

```
List<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if(l % 2 == 0) l += 1;
for(int i=l; i<=r; i += 2){
  arraylist.add(i);
}
return arraylist;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the range starts after `1`, (i.e. `l > 1`), `(l + i % 2) == 1`, which is evaluated as `(l + (i % 2)) == 1` is `false`. `(l + (i % 2)) == 1` can only be true if `l == 1` and `i` is even.

What you should have used is `((l + i) % 2) == 1`.

Besides, the loop's condition should be:

```
i < r-l+1
```

Note that your code could be much more readable (and less error prone) if you simply iterate `i` from `l` to `r`:

```
for (int i=l; i<=r; i++){
    if((i%2)==1)
        arraylist.add(i);
}
```